# Default credentials for jenkins

Tags: jenkins

I have seen almost every document on the web but I could not find the solution to this question of mine. Of course I have installed jenkins and it takes me to the default login page where I enter my admin user and password. My question rises from one of the videos on youtube @ https://youtu.be/EARaltfiPVM on which I posted a comment but did not get an answer yet. The tutorial shows that the jenkins url when entered on the browser FOR THE FIRST TIME AFTER INSTALLATION directly takes you to the jenkins home page instead of login page and this anonymous user literally has all the admin rights from adding plug-ins to creating/running jobs to configuring security!!! Could someone explain is this the old version of jenkins that had this facility? Because otherwise an admin user that I see I have to login with after installation and the anonymous user that this tutorial shows seems to have no difference and which is a disturbing thought. Any inputs would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The version in the video is 1.611 - that release is from the 2015-04-26.

I could be wrong, but I think the default admin user wasn't created at install time back then. This [old Jenkins wiki page](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Standard+Security+Setup) seems to support this .

I don't think it was introduced before version 2.0 on the 2016-04-20 in this feature: **New password-protected setup wizard shown on first run to guide users through installation of popular plugins and setting up an admin user.** ([issue 30749](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-30749), [issue 9598](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-9598))

And refined in version 2.8 on the 2016-06-05 in this feature: [issue 34881](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-34881)

Source: [The old Jenkins changelog](https://jenkins.io/changelog-old/)